# Подскажите какие есть варианты сортировки List<List<String>>

Tags: java

Извиняюсь за возможно простой вопрос, но я новичок и за 5 дней ничего не смог придумать. А вопрос в следующем, есть `List<List<String>>`:

```
[[K1, SK1, SSK1]]

[[K1, SK1, SSK2]]

[[K1, SK1]]

[[K1, SK2]]

[[K1]]

[[K2, SK1, SSK1]]

[[K2, SK1, SSK2]]

[[K2, SK1]]

[[K2]]
```

Как его можно привести к виду:

```
[[K1]] 

[[K1, SK1]] 

[[K1, SK2]] 

[[K1, SK1, SSK1]]

[[K1, SK1, SSK2]] 

[[K2]] 

[[K2, SK1]] 

[[K2, SK1, SSK1]] 

[[K2, SK1, SSK2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

- сначала сортировать по первому элементу
- потом по длине
- потом лексикографически (поэлементно)

Думаю это не та сортировка, которая ожидалась, но по данным угадывать сортировку мне кажется не очень хорошей идей...

В коде используются массивы (соответственно функция сортировки [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator))), компаратор создаётся комбинацией компараторов (метод [`.thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-)). Для списков поменяется только функция сортировки (на [`.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-))

```
String[][] listOfLists = {
        {"K1", "SK1", "SSK1"},
        {"K1", "SK1", "SSK2"},
        {"K1", "SK1"},
        {"K1", "SK2"},
        {"K1"},
        {"K2", "SK1", "SSK1"},
        {"K2", "SK1", "SSK2"},
        {"K2", "SK1"},
        {"K2"}
};

Comparator<String[]> comparator1 = Comparator.comparing(a -> a[0]);
Comparator<String[]> comparator2 = Comparator.comparingInt(list -> list.length);
Comparator<String[]> comparator3 = Arrays::compare;
Comparator<String[]> comparator = comparator1
        .thenComparing(comparator2)
        .thenComparing(comparator3);
Arrays.sort(listOfLists, comparator);
```